Copied URL with queryparams not working when moving to page 2
First time I post here.
My code is working when I go to landing page, filter results and move from page 1 to page 2.
However, when I copy the URL with already filtered queryparams to a new tab, it displays correctly this page 1 but when moving to page 2 it resets filters and display unfiltered results.
Any idea where could lie the problem? my code below.
Thanks,
Joshua
const \[paramsSearch, setParamsSearch\] = useState({
 options: {
  language: null,
  country: null,
  time: { start_time: null, end_time: null },
  rate: { min: null, max: null },
 },
 sort: defaultSortOptionValue(t).split(','),
 page: null,
});

const pushQueryParameter = (page, options, sort) =\> {
 router.push(
  `/tutors?page=${page || 1}` + (options ? options : '') + (sort ? sort : ''),
 );
};

setParamsSearch({
 options: mappedParams,
 sort: sorts,
 page: paramsSearch.page,
});
getTutorList(mappedParams, 1, sorts);

pushQueryParameter(1, queryParams(mappedParams), queryParams(sorts));

const getTutorList = async (
 options = { taught_language: null },
 page = 1,
 sort = null,
) =\> {
 try {
  setIsLoadingTutors(true);
  const response = await api.getTutorListProfiles({
   include: \['degrees', 'avatar_file'\],
   data: {
    filters: options,
    sort: {
     \[sort && sort\[0\]\]: sort && sort\[1\], // ex. rate: sort.ASC
    },
   },
   page: page,
   per: itemsPerPage,
  });
  setMeta(response.meta);
  const formattedTutors = dataFormatter.deserialize(response);
  setTutors(formattedTutors);
  setTutor(formattedTutors\[0\]);
  setIsLoadingTutors(false);
 } catch (e) {
  await handleError(e);
 }
};

const handlePageChange = pageNumber =\> {
 pushQueryParameter(
 pageNumber,
 queryParams(paramsSearch.options),
 queryParams(paramsSearch.sort),
 );
 setParamsSearch({
  options: paramsSearch.options,
  sort: paramsSearch.sort,
  page: pageNumber,
 });
 getTutorList(paramsSearch.options, pageNumber, paramsSearch.sort);
};

export const queryParams = obj => {
 let urlString = '';
 for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj))
  if (value !== null)
   if (typeof value === 'object')
    for (const [subKey, subValue] of Object.entries(value)) {
     if (subValue !== null) urlString += `&${subKey}=${subValue}`;
    }
   else urlString += `&${key}=${value}`;

 return urlString;
};


Can you post the full component? the code where it reads the query param from react-router/the URL is missing (only parts shown are reading from some derivative state -- which is a problem but will come to that when i answer). Currently, would be easier with whole file.

Just updated it with query params

That isnt quite what I meant. Where does it read the query params from the URL? This reads the query params from some state item, and i cant see anywhere where that is itself set by reading window.location or using react routers useLocation hook to retrieve them from the URL. If you don't have this, that would be your issue. It would mean your query params are only "for show" and don't actually drive the state.
